# Do I need to delete a "new" allocated thread when I know it has finished?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the following code (part of a class):

```
void MyClass::foo() {
    //...
    mutex_.lock();
    if (state_ == first) {
        mutex_.unlock();    
        thread_ = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::bar, this)))
    }
    mutex_.unlock();
    //...
}

void MyClass::bar() {
    //...
    while (true) {
        //...
        mutex_.lock();
        if (state_ == last) {
            mutex_.unlock();
            state_ = first;
            break;
        }
        mutex_.unlock();
        //...
    }
}
```

This code makes sure that whenever `thread_` is assigned to point to a new thread, the previous thread will have already finished (or, in the first time, have not been started at all).

Is this code safe from memory leaks/are there things I've missed? I am not sure whether a thread which has finished needs to be deallocated with `delete`.

Comment: Wouldn't `boost::shared_ptr` take care of deallocation for you?

Comment: I don't know enough about boost::shared_ptr to be able to say that with certainty.

Comment: 1. Anything ***absolutely anything*** (including threads) you allocate with `new` should be deallocated with with `delete`. It's your responsibility to ensure this happens. (How you _ensure_ it, is up to you.) 2. One technique to ensure something is deallocated is to assign it to an appropriate [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). E.g. A shared point is "reference-counted" meaning a count of the total number references to the same instance is automatically maintained. When the last reference is reassigned or goes out of scope, the object is `delete`d automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: @CraigYoung So for my case, the answer would be that I do not need to call delete myself since it will happen automatically when `thread_` is reassigned to point to a different thread?